# Connecting Scarlett 2i2 to Midas DL32 digital stage box

Tags: setup

Will I need to use a direct box to connect the Scarlett 2i2 to the Midas DL32, or can I plug directly from the TRS outputs to the XLR inputs?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do that.  If you can edit your question with more details about what you want to do, we can offer a better answer. The Midas has XLR pre-amps, just like the Scarlett does. The Scarlet TRS outputs are at line level, just like the Midas outputs, so no, you would not want to send the line outs of the Scarlett to the low impedance XLR inputs of the DL32

Answer (score 1):

It migth be possible to connect directly from the TRS outputs to the XLR inputs. But I would never do that. I would always use a DI Box, always with a transformer and ground lift. ( Or two for stereo ). This is not necessarily the only way to do it, but it avoids several problems:

1) The outputs are at line level ( a few volts ), but the inputs expect microphone level ( millivolts ) . Often this can be compensated for, but not always.

2) The Midas may output 48V phantom power for microphones, the Scarlett might survive that on its outputs, but it is not certain.

3) The ground potential may vara quite a bit on stage, and especially if you go off to a remote mixing desc. We often end up with hum ( 50 or 60 Hertz ) when not using a DI.

Comment: Since I never got an answer from my comment, and you have a good answer, I'd like to add that if the intent of sending from the Scarlett is to capture a couple of signals to record before sending to House, then an XLR splitter is probably the best option. There are splitter boxes available that are similar to a DI box.  A mini mixer with balanced outputs would also work.